Need to store(save) some configuration data for a MsTeams Tab App
I am developing a MsTeams app using ms-teams-latest-js on Blazor .Net framework. While adding the tab during configuration, I ask an environment-url of my application then display my application in an iframe in a tab.
However, for other users in the same chat/channel, I want to re-use the same configured environment-url that the first user has configured. Is there a way in MsTeams js to store some data for the whole chat/channel?

You can store configuration data by using the microsoftTeams.settings.setSettings method. This method allows you to save settings that can be retrieved later by other users in the same chat/channel. To retrieve the stored configuration data, you can use the microsoftTeams.settings.getSettings method. This method allows you to access the settings that were previously saved. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/%40microsoft/teams-js/microsoftteams.settings?view=msteams-client-js-1.13.1#functions
